# Загрузка xml в память Android'a из интернета

Tags: android, файлы

Здравствуйте, создаю приложение, которое парсит *XML* файл, файл находится в папке с проектом `res/xml`, парсится без проблем. Но мне нужно, что бы при первом запуске этот xml загружался в память телефона из интернета и потом уже с памяти парсился. Подскажите как это сделать, сам найти не смог.

Вот как у меня происходит загрузка xml в парсер

```
try {
            XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.troll);
```

Comment: Как нагрузить файл с в парсер с телефона я нашёл, а вот как загрузить этот xml с сайта в телефон найти не получается.

Comment: думаю вот это вам поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395154/android-read-an-xml-file-with-http-get     
а вообще это стандартная задача и гуглится за пару минут.